# How to lookup an array of objects based upon another array of objects?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can I filter values of `input` array based on the `user` field (if that field exists in `filterArray`) and get `expectedOuput`

```js
const filterArray = [{
  user: "bcasey1",
  userfullname: "Bertha Casey"
}, {
  user: "admin1",
  userfullname: "Administrator 1"
}];

const input = [{
    "id": 133557,
    "user": "bcasey1",
    "userfullname": "Bertha Casey",
    "commentTypeId": 2,
    "annotationPrimaryId": 141614,
    "comment": "Red color on ravioli is not true, fix",
    "deleted": false,
    "historyno": "133557-0",
    "timestamp": "Tue Apr 24 10: 40: 42 CDT 2018",
    "type": "rectangle",
    "commentNum": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 134038,
    "user": "admin",
    "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
    "commentTypeId": 1,
    "annotationPrimaryId": 142286,
    "comment": "test123",
    "deleted": false,
    "historyno": "134038-0",
    "timestamp": "Mon Jul 8 22: 15: 18 CDT 2019",
    "type": "rectangle",
    "commentNum": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 134039,
    "user": "admin1",
    "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
    "commentTypeId": 2,
    "annotationPrimaryId": 142287,
    "comment": "test234",
    "deleted": false,
    "historyno": "134039-0",
    "timestamp": "Mon Jul 8 22: 15: 35 CDT 2019",
    "type": "rectangle",
    "commentNum": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 134112,
    "user": "admin",
    "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
    "commentTypeId": 3,
    "annotationPrimaryId": 142361,
    "comment": "sadasdasd",
    "deleted": false,
    "historyno": "134112-0",
    "timestamp": "Wed Jul 17 13: 03: 55 CDT 2019",
    "type": "rectangle",
    "commentNum": 4
  },

];

const expectedOuput = [{
    "id": 133557,
    "user": "bcasey1",
    "userfullname": "Bertha Casey",
    "commentTypeId": 2,
    "annotationPrimaryId": 141614,
    "comment": "Red color on ravioli is not true, fix",
    "deleted": false,
    "historyno": "133557-0",
    "timestamp": "Tue Apr 24 10: 40: 42 CDT 2018",
    "type": "rectangle",
    "commentNum": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 134039,
    "user": "admin1",
    "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
    "commentTypeId": 2,
    "annotationPrimaryId": 142287,
    "comment": "test234",
    "deleted": false,
    "historyno": "134039-0",
    "timestamp": "Mon Jul 8 22: 15: 35 CDT 2019",
    "type": "rectangle",
    "commentNum": 3
  },
];

console.log('expectedOuput',expectedOuput);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter based on whether [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) users in `filterArray` share the user property.

```
const expectedOuput = input.filter(p => filterArray.some(user => user.user == p.user))
```

This looks through the `filterArray` every time which is not efficient. If the lists get big it would be worth extracting the elements from `filterArray` into some sort of hash for quicker searching.

```js
const filterArray = [{
  user: "bcasey1",
  userfullname: "Bertha Casey"
}, {
  user: "admin1",
  userfullname: "Administrator 1"
}];



const input = [{
    "id": 133557,
    "user": "bcasey1",
    "userfullname": "Bertha Casey",
    "commentTypeId": 2,
    "annotationPrimaryId": 141614,
    "comment": "Red color on ravioli is not true, fix",
    "deleted": false,
    "historyno": "133557-0",
    "timestamp": "Tue Apr 24 10: 40: 42 CDT 2018",
    "type": "rectangle",
    "commentNum": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 134038,
    "user": "admin",
    "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
    "commentTypeId": 1,
    "annotationPrimaryId": 142286,
    "comment": "test123",
    "deleted": false,
    "historyno": "134038-0",
    "timestamp": "Mon Jul 8 22: 15: 18 CDT 2019",
    "type": "rectangle",
    "commentNum": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 134039,
    "user": "admin1",
    "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
    "commentTypeId": 2,
    "annotationPrimaryId": 142287,
    "comment": "test234",
    "deleted": false,
    "historyno": "134039-0",
    "timestamp": "Mon Jul 8 22: 15: 35 CDT 2019",
    "type": "rectangle",
    "commentNum": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 134112,
    "user": "admin",
    "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
    "commentTypeId": 3,
    "annotationPrimaryId": 142361,
    "comment": "sadasdasd",
    "deleted": false,
    "historyno": "134112-0",
    "timestamp": "Wed Jul 17 13: 03: 55 CDT 2019",
    "type": "rectangle",
    "commentNum": 4
  },

];

const expectedOuput = input.filter(p => filterArray.some(user => user.user == p.user))

console.log('expectedOuput',expectedOuput);
```

Comment: I didnt knew `some()` even existed thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Set` of the user names to filter....then Array#filter() checking if user is in that set.

```js
const users = new Set( filterArray.map(({user}) => user))

const res = input.filter(({user}) => users.has(user))

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script>
  const filterArray = [{
    user: "bcasey1",
    userfullname: "Bertha Casey"
  }, {
    user: "admin1",
    userfullname: "Administrator 1"
  }];

  const input = [{
      "id": 133557,
      "user": "bcasey1",
      "userfullname": "Bertha Casey",
      "commentTypeId": 2,
      "annotationPrimaryId": 141614,
      "comment": "Red color on ravioli is not true, fix",
      "deleted": false,
      "historyno": "133557-0",
      "timestamp": "Tue Apr 24 10: 40: 42 CDT 2018",
      "type": "rectangle",
      "commentNum": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 134038,
      "user": "admin",
      "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
      "commentTypeId": 1,
      "annotationPrimaryId": 142286,
      "comment": "test123",
      "deleted": false,
      "historyno": "134038-0",
      "timestamp": "Mon Jul 8 22: 15: 18 CDT 2019",
      "type": "rectangle",
      "commentNum": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 134039,
      "user": "admin1",
      "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
      "commentTypeId": 2,
      "annotationPrimaryId": 142287,
      "comment": "test234",
      "deleted": false,
      "historyno": "134039-0",
      "timestamp": "Mon Jul 8 22: 15: 35 CDT 2019",
      "type": "rectangle",
      "commentNum": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 134112,
      "user": "admin",
      "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
      "commentTypeId": 3,
      "annotationPrimaryId": 142361,
      "comment": "sadasdasd",
      "deleted": false,
      "historyno": "134112-0",
      "timestamp": "Wed Jul 17 13: 03: 55 CDT 2019",
      "type": "rectangle",
      "commentNum": 4
    },

  ];
</script>
```

Comment: This runs faster than mark's so i will accept this https://jsfiddle.net/dota2pro/9py1zt36/6/

Comment: Right because other approches have to loop through the array every iteration (even if it's only a partial loop) whereas a set lookup is `o(1)`

Comment: @dota2pro This is a fine solution and we're talking microseconds here — but whether this is faster or slower depends *a lot* on the size of the lists your are dealing with. Creating the set is not cheap — in fact this code [runs 2 to 3 times slower on your input](https://jsperf.com/somevhash/1). The benefits of the set won't start to materialize until the lists a significantly larger.

Answer (score 0):

to return the object:

```
function filterByUserType(userType) {
  return input.filter((item) => {
    return (item.user === userType)
  })
}

console.log(filterByUserType('bcasey1'));
```

To see if it exists:

```
function hasUserType(userType) {
  return input.some((item) => {
    return (item.user === userType) ? true : false;
  })
}

console.log(hasUserType('bcasey1'));
```